# Special Character in password

Tags: oracle, linux, sqlplus

I'm Trying to connect to a remote DB using Sqlplus, but  the password contains a special character (!).
The SID is working fine, but Sqlplus is complaining about it when I use the ! in the password

```
/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/bin/sqlplus -s bloth/hods!@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=remoteServer)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SUDFR)))
```

> ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect

on the other hand, when I remove the special character I get

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works with single quotes.

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ sqlplus u1/u1!@(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1521)(host=o71.balazs.vm))(connect_data=(service_name=min18_o71)))
-bash: !@: event not found
[oracle@o71 ~]$ sqlplus 'u1/u1!@(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1521)(host=o71.balazs.vm))(connect_data=(service_name=min18_o71)))'

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Mar 2 09:07:54 2019
Version 18.5.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Sat Mar 02 2019 09:07:15 +01:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.5.0.0.0

SQL>
```

Comment: Bravissimo!! It works like a Charm

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix is change the password.  There are several special characters that become problematic when used in a password, because the OS (or other intervening software) uses those characters as an indicator.

Certainly the '@' and '$' characters fall into this category.
The '@' because sqlplus itself sees that as the terminator indicateing that what follows is the net service name.  So

```
sqlplus scott/myp@ssword@orcl
```

is seen as a password of 'myp', and a net service name of 'ssword'

And '$' is problematic on *nix platforms because the OS sees it as indicating to substitute the value of an environment variable. So assume you have an environment variable name word=fubar, with

```
sqlplus scott/mypas$word@orcl
```

The shell processor will change that to 'scott/mypasfubar@orcl' before calling sqlplus and passing the rest of the line.

This doesn't mean you can't use any special characters in passwords, but you have to be careful about which ones you allow.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own that DB, it's a remote DB.

Comment: Also the confort of anyone using sqlplus should not drive the guidelines for setting passwords. In real life, applications will connect to databases. For thick clients, I imagine the user who connects will be prompted for the password, so special characters are irrelevant. For web applications (running inside some application server), the password is going to come from some config file or wallet. Here also special characters play no role.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind - I don't want to get into a spitting match, but I'd have to respond with "perhaps in your perfectly imagined world." In my 30+ years in this business I've seen a lot of installations that don't match your expectations. I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree.